Do we want a parts-database or parts-library tag?
I noticed that there a lot of questions that mention a "part library", but we don't have a tag like "part-database" or "parts-library" to include those.
We have a set-database tag, but that doesn't seem to fit since parts are not sets.  Am I missing something or is there an opportunity for a useful tag here?
I got started on this while trying to find better tags for jncraton's question.  I don't think we have enough on 3D rendering for a tag that specific yet, but the "parts-database" aspect of it seems worthy of a tag to me.
I prefer "part-database" for consistency with "set-database", but "parts-library" is how people seem to use it and should at least be an alias if not the primary tag.

I added the part-database tag and created parts-library as a synonym.

That makes sense to me. I like part-database with parts-library as an alias.
